# Retrieve center point the viewer is looking at from view/perspective matrix

Tags: gl-matrix

I use the glMatrix's method: `mat4.lookAt(out, eye, center, up)` to set a camera view when a WebGL model is rendering.

After the model is rendered, I need to retrieve the `center` attribute from view/perspective matrix. I know how to retrieve the `eye` attribute, but I have no idea how to get the `center` one. How can I do that?

This is the `mat4.lookAt` method I use:
http://glmatrix.net/docs/mat4.js.html#line1366

Comment: Not 100% on this one but for matrix M should it not be `M*(0,0,0)-M*(0,0,1)`? In any case you can't get the center that was used as an input because if is transformed to `forward = normalized(center-eye)` which means that distance is lost forever. Not sure what you are looking for though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get the actual center since it was normalized. You can get a center position that will generate the same look at. I think it would be this.

```
camera = mat4.inverse(mat4.create(), view);
up = camera.slice(4, 7);
eye = camera.slice(12, 15);
negativeZ = camera.slice(8, 11);
center = vec3.scaleAndAdd(vec3.create(), eye, negativeZ, -1);
```

That center will be one unit in front of the eye. Change the `-1` to `-1 * units` to make it further away from the eye. In other words `-2` would be two units in front, `-3` would be 3 units in front etc.

Here's a test

```js
const eye = [1, 2, 3];
const center = [4, 5, 6];
const up = [0, 1, 0];
const view = mat4.lookAt(mat4.create(), eye, center, up);

const camera = mat4.invert(mat4.create(), view);
const newUp = camera.slice(4, 7);
const newEye = camera.slice(12, 15);
const negativeZ = camera.slice(8, 11);
const newCenter = vec3.scaleAndAdd(vec3.create(), newEye, negativeZ, -1);

const newView = mat4.lookAt(mat4.create(), newEye, newCenter, newUp);

// show difference between view and newView
console.log(view.map((v, i) => (v - newView[i]).toFixed(6)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.4.0/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

[This article explains the parts of a camera matrix and what a view matrix is](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html).